# Why can’t every element emit all the colours from the emission spectrum

Tags: quantum-chemistry

If there is an infinite number of levels, this means that every electron can jump from as many variations as possible. Hence, why can’t every element emit every colour?
Please don’t use very complicated theory because I’ve just started my A levels.

Comment: I guess even you can distinguish infinity of real number set and infinity of Ry . (1/n1^2 - 1/n2^2), If we consider for simplicity a hydrogen atom. BTW, a potassium atom with n=600 has size about 0.1 mm, so practically,, it is not infinity.

Comment: Simply put, **"infinitely many numbers"** is not the same as **"all numbers"**.

Answer (score 3):

> If there is an infinite number of levels

Yes, but the key point you are missing is that they are not equally spaced. The energy levels are not like stair cases (equally spaced). The electronic energy levels tend to converge. After that, you have basically provided enough energy to electron that it can overcome the attraction of the nucleus and leave the atom. If you recall, this is called ionization.

This figure illustrates the concept of convergence.

As an exercise, try to plot 1/$n^2$ as a function of n in Excel, where n=1 to 20. See how rapidly it converges to zero.

[image]